# request.addlistener в Node.js

Tags: node.js, события

В процессе изучения Node.js я уже успел поделать некоторые простые действия с объектами запроса и ответа, которые передаются почти в любой обработчик почти чего угодно.
Но тут дело доходит до node-static, и в его описании я вижу вот это:

```
require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
request.addListener('end', function () {
    fileServer.serve(request, response);
}).resume();
}).listen(8080);
```

Объясните, что же такое для Node этот `request`, почему у него есть такой метод как `addListener` и что значит "слушать" `end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала стоит сказать, что node.js имеет событийную модель и асинхронен по своей сути. Поэтому для работы с ним используются различные подписки.

`request` же, в свою очередь, предоставляет интерфейс для работы со входным потоком данных.

`addListener` добавляет "слушателя" - колбек, который сработает после определённых действий.

В вашем случае `request.addListener('end'` осуществляет подписку на событие окончания принятия данных из входного потока. Переданная функция вызовется, когда поток закончит отдавать данные серверу.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. В каких случаях может быть важно ловить "end"?  Просто не встречал его прежде в базовых примерах.